# How can calculate combinations on 2nd level array?

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

Sorry if the question is not clear. I don't know how to build it.
I need to calculate all possible combination for a given array of arrays. I Better make a graphical example:

a,b,c

0,1,2,3

0

A,B

0,1,2

Possible results would be:
a00A0 and b00A0 and b30B1....

So basically it's rotating every array for each position and build all possible strings. Like trying to open one of those 3-digit combination chains we had when where young and we forgot the key.

Comment: Are you looking for the amount of possible combinations, or to generate all possibilities?

Comment: It's not the only way, but consider a recursive solution. You're basically stepping through a tree

Comment: I'm not specialized in math programming, so I basically started to build the array and calculated possible elements matrix (redundant) and lost focus while trying to build some loops and recursive functions... so nothing.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JFTxJ I need to generate the possibilities.

Comment: Why don't you simply use 5 nested loops? or you want a generic solution ?

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks, I wrote it before filling the tags and as similar questions appeared (none clear or usable) I totally forgotten.

Comment: @Shaharyar As the main array will change, I need some dynamic solution. In fact, the first requirement it's a dimension of 22 in the first array and 0,2-3 on the secondaries (0=fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Cartesian Product of a number of sequences not defined at compile time.

Eric Lippert describes how to solve this problem in [this blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

The code from that article is as follows:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>
    (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct =
        new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

You can then pass in your sequences of sequences to this function and get out the sequence of all possible combinations.

Comment: Thnx a lot. Can you elaborate? So embarrassing, but looking at it I don't know even how to call it. Or if that's exactly what I need before making a new project for it. ;)

(And I supposed to own a solution for mixture that used a linear math calculation core. I'm getting so old)

Comment: @Sergio As I said in my answer, you pass in a sequences of sequences, and get out a sequences of combinations (each combination is one sequence).  That's how you call it.  You currently have N sequences.  Put all of them into a sequences of sequences to call it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that seems an extension of IEnumerable. So it may be extending an Enumerable of? Enumerable of char?

Comment: @Sergio It's an extension of `IEnumerable<IEnumearble<T>>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.  That means you need to have a sequence of sequences of whatever, not just a sequence of whatever.

Comment: Right, just trying to figure out how to rework all the ArrayLists building I had. That was another odisea alone.

Comment: @Sergio You should never use `ArrayList`.  It is entirely obsolete.  You should use generic collection types instead, such as `List`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54939/discussion-between-sergio-and-servy).